# jQuery ajax return data crossover confusion

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, setinterval

I'm having the peculiar problem where two separately created $.ajax functions are used, with completely different urls, but for some reason the returned data objects seem to get merged.

Both functions are called separately and independently from within separate `window.setInterval` timers. Both ajax code blocks are placed in separate functions.

When the `$.each(data, function(i, item)` function is called in the success condition of ajax #2 (I only use the `each` to debug), the alert box outputs ALL of the data, including the data from ajax #1. So, the data object that should only be returned from ajax #2 (username, picture, gender) is also outputting the properties of the data object from ajax #1.

Since both data objects have a property "success", and since I use a success == "1" as a condition for other operations, this problem is breaking my program. For example, if ajax #1 returns a "data.success = 1", this seems to trigger the `if(success == 1){ loop through data }` in ajax #2, which is definitely not supposed to happen.

ajax #1:

```
function getClientProfile(){
    var url = "http://www.mydomain.com/a_folder/getClientProfile.php?callback="+callback;
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    async: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonpCallback: callback,
    success: function(data) {
       if(data.success == "1"){
           secret = data.secret;
           email = data.email;
           timezone = data.timezone;
           events = data.events;
           links = data.links;
           website = data.website;
           domain = data.domain;
           address = data.address;
       }
    },
    error: function (){
          //alert("flub: " + url);
    }
  });
}
```

ajax #2:

```
function getLoggedDate() {
    var url = "http://www.mydomain.com/a_folder/getloggeddata.php?callback=" + callback;
    //alert( url );
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        async: true,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonpCallback: callback,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.success == "1") {
                $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                    alert("success: " + i + " = " + item);
                });
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Is there a 'callback' function defined by you?
If not, I think you don't need to define it. dataType: 'jsonp' is enough.

Comment: The callback is defined by me. It is a global callback that equals a UTC time, concatenated with a client id. It is used in the php files to create indices and keys for database insert records. That way every callback for every browser instance is unique.